# Eclipse and executing an external app on the current file

Tags: eclipse

I know that eclipse has its own formatter for C++, but it's not so advanced like the Uncrustify. I wonder whether it is possible to execute some external application (the Uncrustify) on the current working file when I press some shortcut like Ctrl+Shift+F? Is Eclipse customizable in such way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the application as an external tool - see `Run` -> `External Tools`. Remember to refresh the project resources as the workspace will otherwise be out-of-sync with the real files. See

[image]